# Regex Replace no change

Tags: c#, regex

Sorry for not coming up with a better title. Perhaps someone can help me figure out why my regex replace is not currently working. So I have the following function:

```
string installlocation = session.CustomActionData["location"];
string regex = "add key=\x22Directory\x22 value=\x22([^\x22]*)\x22";
string replacement = "add key='Directory' value='" + installlocation + "'";
string input = File.ReadAllText(@Path.Combine(installlocation,"DeliveryService.exe.config"));
Regex rgx = new Regex(regex);
string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);
File.WriteAllText(@Path.Combine(installlocation, "DeliveryService.exe.config"), result);
```

Where installlocation = C:\Program Files (x86)\Wizard

There are no errors during runtime and when the supposed results are written back to the file, the file contains the same information. Nothing is changed. Now for reference here is the file being searched and replaced:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Directory" value="" />
    <add key="Timer" value="5" />
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
  </appSettings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
  </startup>
  <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

What I am expecting to see is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key='Directory' value='C:\Program Files (x86\Wizard' />
    <add key="Timer" value="5" />
    <add key="ClientSettingsProvider.ServiceUri" value="" />
  </appSettings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
  </startup>
  <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I also have verified my regex with regex101 and it should work. I also am following [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) article about regex replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `\x22` and when your pattern contains escape sequences, enclose it in a [verbatim string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) `@"...."` or use double backslashes.

So you can write it like this:

```
string regex = @"add key=""Directory"" value=""([^""]*)""";
```

*(double quote is escaped by an other double quote)*

As an aside, a regex replace (as a simple text replace) is not the way to go to change the value of an attribute in an xml file. Use an XML Parser.

Comment: That worked! Interesting that the verbatim string didn't work but this did. I guess that is one of the caveats of the .net regex versus others.

Comment: @Kyle: This is also a verbatim string literal.

Answer (score 0):

Using verbatim string literal will do the work:

```
string regex = @"add key=\x22Directory\x22 value=\x22([^\x22]*)\x22";
```

The point here is that either you can use a `""` or the hex pattern `\x22` for the double quotation mark inside a verbatim string literal.

[image]

This sample code is also working:

```
string regex = @"add key=\x22Directory\x22 value=\x22([^\x22]*)\x22";
string input = "<add key=\"Directory\" value=\"\" />";
Regex rgx = new Regex(regex);
string replacement = "<REPLACEMENT>";
string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);
```

Comment: Actually, your regex was good from the very beginning, no need to replace the hex code with doubled double quotes. The main point was using the verbatim string literal with the regex notation you had (with single escapes around the regex metacharacters. You could as well use `string regex = "add key=\\x22Directory\\x22 value=\\x22([^\\x22]*)\\x22";` - and it would work.